# What is the equivalent in Jython of the VBA code below?

Tags: python, vba, jython

What is the equivalent in Jython of the VBA code below?

```
If Left(varValues(15),4)="0002" Then
    Result = "0008_5_" & Right(varValues(15),3) 
End If
```

Comment: This is a **very** poor question.  Why don't you take a look at the [help] and [ask].

Comment: The code isn't valid VBA. `"0002"` is a valid string literal, and `"""0002"""` is also a valid string literal (with properly escaped quote marks), but `""0002""` is a syntax error. What string are you trying to construct?

Comment: I am sorry for the typo. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `startswith` in place of `Left` and a slice with a negative index in place of `Right`:

```
s = varValues[15]
if s.startswith("0002"):
    result = "0008_5_" + s[-3:]
```